# Can I know how to add TrustedHosts in powershell

Tags: powershell

Am using the following command to add but showing an error that need to set the policy to "not configured". Can any one help me in this?

[image: screenshot of error]

Comment: Are you working in an AD environment that uses Group policy, if so are you the administrator?

Comment: Yes, am the administrator

Comment: From the error it looks like your trusted hosts are set using GPO. On your computer run `gpresults /H report.html` and check to see if it is set. It should be here: `Computer Configuration / Policies / Administrative Templates / Windows Components / Windows Remote Management (WinRM) / WinRM Client / Trusted Hosts`

Comment: @jrider tagging you so you can submit an answer

Answer (score 0):

From the error it looks like your trusted hosts are set using GPO. 
On your computer run `gpresults /H report.html` and check to see if it is set.

It should be here: `Computer Configuration / Policies / Administrative Templates / Windows Components / Windows Remote Management (WinRM) / WinRM Client / Trusted Hosts`

You can change it to `Not Configured` or you can just add the host to the configuration